# Does e-mail masking for spam protection actually matter?

Tags: html, email, spam-prevention

I've used different techniques for masking email addresses for years now, ranging from javascript that add together different parts, to CSS-methods that use right to left and other things.

But does it really matter? In my eyes it's still pretty trivial to write a crawler that parses most of these methods. Are most of the email harvesters really that far behind?

Comment: Good question! My subjective impression is that it doesn't really matter. But it would be interesting to get hard facts on this

Comment: Depends on how good the crawler is. In the end, if something is visible in some way to the end user, then a crawler can see it. Attacks only ever get BETTER, never worse. Today's absolutely bulletproof unbreakable captcha is tomorrow's running joke in the spammer's favorite watering hole.